# How to create password-protected strong-name key file without Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, strongname

`sn -k keyname.snk` creates a basic strong-name keyfile but how do I create a password-protected version `keyname.pfx` from scratch?

I have no existing `snk`, I just want to create a entirely new file for a new project.

Comment: Makecert is the command line.

Comment: @LexLi please add it as an answer so I can up vote and accept it : )

Comment: OpenSSL example can be found from here, https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html